# The perpendicular bisected of the line segment joining $P(1,4)$ and $Q(k,3)$ has $y$-intercept $4$. Then the possible value of k is

Tags: analytic-geometry, solution-verification

Slope of line $PQ$ is 
$$m=\frac{1}{1-k}$$
The slope perpendicular to it will be 
$k-1$

Since the line is a bisector of PQ it will pass through 
$(\frac{1+k}{2},\frac 72)$
Then 
$$y=mx+c$$
$$\frac 72 =(k-1)(\frac {k+1}{2})+4$$
$$\frac{-1}{2}=\frac{k^2-1}{2}$$
$$k=0$$
But the answer given is $-4$. What’s going wrong?

Comment: This is absolutely correct. Nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. Your answer is fine. Note that, when $k=0$, $Q=(0,3)$. Since $P=(1,4)$, the slope of the line passing through $P$ and $Q$ is $1$, and therefore the slope of the perpendicular bisector of $P$ and $Q$ is $-1$. But the line passing through $\left(\frac12,\frac72\right)$ with slope $-1$ clearly passes through $(0,4)$ too.

Of course, this doesn't prove that the answer $k=-4$ is wrong (although it *is* wrong), but it shows that asserting that that's the only answer cannot be right.

Comment: Sure. **You** did it, right?!

Answer (score 1):

$$(\frac{k+1}{2},\frac{7}{2})+t(1,k-1)=(0,4)$$
[$$\begin{cases}
k+1+2t=0,\\
7-t(k-1)=4
\end{cases}$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%28k%2B1%29%2F2%2C7%2F2%7D%2Bt*%7B1%2Ck-1%7D%3D%7B0%2C4%7D)
Since this is a system of linear equations, it has $0,\,1\hbox{ or }\infty$ solutions.
$$k=0,\,t=-\frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

Option:

The perpendicalur bisector intersects the $y$-axis in $(0,4)$.

A circle with center $(0,4)$ passes through $P(1,4)$ and $Q(k,3)$.

Radius of this circle: $r=\sqrt{1^2+0^2}=1$;

Hence

$1^2=k^2+(4-3)^2= k^2+1^2$;

$k=0$;